# CSS mixing relative and absolute height

Tags: css, html

Is there a way to use both absolute (in px) and relative heights for html div elements? I'd like to create a navigation bar and want the remainder to be used by the content div.

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5YHX7/801/) (`.bot` needs to allocate the remaining height). In the example it has a scroll bar which is undesired.

Edit:
The more I [read about it](http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm), the more I realise that this seems to be a real problem. I certainly don't intend to carry through the margin to all nested levels...

Edit2:
I was after a solution that allows me to split `.bot` into two equal height divs which means the bot div cannot be just overlayed by the top one. I have found a solution (using `calc`), but had never heard about it before and are not sure if it's save to be used.

Comment: I usually just cheat and make the body background color match the background color of the bottom-most part of the footer: http://jsfiddle.net/5YHX7/802/ -- 800+ revisions? holy cow...

Comment: it's possibly easier for us if you can provide us with an image of your desired output, and possibly a further explanation on what they should do

Comment: Sure. See my answer using `calc` below. That's how it should look like (at least if you use Chrome; not sure how it looks in other browsers). A fixed size header + 2 equally sized divs underneath that scale when the window height changes is what I'm after...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how good of an answer this is in terms of browser compatibility, but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BxZds/1/) seems to be working in chrome. Apparently, there's a `calc` function that dynamically updates the result in css. Can anyone comment on this solution?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc If you support Opera you will probably want something else.

Comment: Good overview. I'm not terribly fussed about Opera (especially since they will go with Webkit in the not too distant future).

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the output by adding `margin-top` -ve value to and add an empty div to specify the height

**HTML**

```
 <div class='top'>
        some top stuff...
    </div>

    <div class='bot'>
      <div class="space"></div>        
     some bot stuff...
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.space{height:40px}
.bot {
    margin-top:-40px;
    z-index:0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5YHX7/806/)**

Comment: Thanks. See my comment at Pavlo's reply. Your suggestion doesn't seem to be working for [nested divs](http://jsfiddle.net/5YHX7/808/) (which I admit I should have mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

for the first question:

```
.top {
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 position: absolute;
}
.bot {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin-top:40px;
}
```

for the second question it applies to it's parent element unless it's created fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. `.bot` will not get `100%-40px` space which you can see if you split it by inserting 2x50%-height divs. The upper one of them will have less space (40px less) as it flows into (under) the top one.

Comment: this is due to the line text you added above the two divs. remove that and the ratio should be fixed.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle? I was trying it before and couldn't get it working this way...

Comment: Is it just me, or is there a white bar at the top (above the blue one)?

Comment: for some odd reason there is if you remove the margin-top it's gone. I guess it's not functioning correctly. for me this normally works I guess I didn't include the css reset I normally use to fix most problems like these. this might work: http://jsfiddle.net/GAREy/3/

Answer (score 0):

This will surely help you out... tested on ie,ff,chrome

```
html, body { 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 0; 
}

.top {
    height: 7%;
    min-height: 38px;
    max-height: 38px;
    background-color: green;
}

.bot {
    height: 93%;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
}

.half {
    height: 50%;
    background-color: pink;
    position: relative;    
}

.half2 {
    height: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;    
}
```

Comment: Nice try. I was toying with this idea myself, but it fails if you enlarge the window, so that 10% > 40px.

Comment: I might have made a mistake, but I can't get this to work: http://jsfiddle.net/P2Xwc/ See the yellow block that isn't 50%.

Comment: Still not working (the yellow box is smaller than the pink one). http://jsfiddle.net/2dFT6/ I think I have a solution (using `calc`), but thanks anyway for the time to answer this question.